# Writing a date range in vertical format

Tags: orthography, copywriting

How would one write a range of dates in vertical format? For instance, 2017-18 or 2017-2018.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are kanji typically used in times and dates?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17423/are-kanji-typically-used-in-times-and-dates)

Comment: @naruto Not necessarily, but [one of the answers](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17450/25446) addresses how to write dates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've tried looking for the proper way of writing date ranges vertically in Japanese but haven't found any specific ones, but if you're going to express just the year then you could write:

> 2
> 0
> 1
> 7
> 年
> 1
> 2
> 月
> 3
> 0
> 日
> |
> 2
> 0
> 1
> 8
> 年
> 1
> 月
> 5
> 日

See [here](https://www.benricho.org/kanji/kansuji-tate.html) (in Japanese).

Comment: Just leave out the month 月 and day 日 if you they're not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to write it (See [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17450/9831) for detail), but I personally usually write like...

[image]

Comment: 縦のまっすぐの線（こんなやつの縦版 →「ー」）のいいのがワードでみつからないんですけど・・

Comment: どうもありがとうございます  I am also curious about if the year range was printed in a Japanese magazine, would they use this same format with kanji numbers for vertical format. Would there be the same sort of separation for [ ~ ]?